# Вывод нескольких классов на 1 url адрес

Tags: python, django, классы, views

Обращаюсь с такой проблемой: нужно вывести несколько классов (на данный момент их 2), которые содержатся в views.py на 1 url страницу. Цель: вывод 3 постов одного типа (rig) и 1 пост другого типа (article) на главную страницу. На сайте присутствуют отдельные страницы для вывода всех rig и article
Файл views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rigs.models import Rig
from news.models import Article
from django.views.generic import ListView

class ShowRigView(ListView):
    model = Rig
    template_name = 'main_page/main_page.html'
    context_object_name = 'rig'
    ordering = ['-date']
    paginate_by = 3

    def get_context_data(self, **kwards):
        ctx = super(ShowRigView, self).get_context_data(**kwards)
        return ctx

class ShowArticleView(ListView):
    model = Article
    template_name = 'main_page/main_page.html'
    context_object_name = 'article'
    ordering = ['-date']
    paginate_by = 1

    def get_context_data(self, **kwards):
        ctx = super(ShowArticleView, self).get_context_data(**kwards)
        ctx['title'] = 'MCStore'
        return ctx

class ShowMainView(ShowRigView, ShowArticleView):
    template_name = 'main_page/main_page.html'
```

Файл urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.ShowMainView.as_view(), name='main_page'),
]
```

Есть идеи, как это реализовать? У меня был более простой, но непонятный мне вариант. Можно ли добавить 2 класса в urls.py? Типо такого:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.ShowRigView.as_view(), views.ShowArticleView.as_view() name='main_page'),
]
```

Очень надеюсь на помощь и буду благодарен.

Comment: 2 класса в urls.py в Django добавить НЕЛЬЗЯ! Т.к. path принимает только один аргумент `view`: `path(route, view, kwargs=None, name=None)`
Ознакомьтесь с документацией Django: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/urls/#django.urls.path

Comment: Один из вариантов решения - определение одного контроллера, который в зависимости от входных данных возвращает соответствующие данные (или `Rig` или `Article`) или все данные (`Rig` и `Article`)). Под каждый вариант придётся корректировать шаблоны.

Comment: @AlTheOne а можешь пожалуйста подсказать, что именно нужно изменить? Тот код, который выше, это главаня страница сайта на которую выводятся 3 самые новые объекта (rig) и 1 статья (article). То есть необходимо выводить и то и то. И ещё хотел спросить, а почему не работает то, что я сделал. Я вывожу 1 класс, который принимает значения от двух других. В итоге выводиться только то, что стоит первое в скобках.

Comment: @AlTheOne ещё был вариант запихнуть эти 2 класа в def и выводить его. Но выдаёт ошибку HttpResponse. Пробовал в таком случае в конце добавить return render и путь к шаблону, но оно выводило страницу без объектов тех двух классов

Comment: > `Я вывожу 1 класс, который принимает значения от двух других. В итоге выводиться только то, что стоит первое в скобках.`

Это связано с правилами наследования. В дереве наследования был найден класс,который находится левее первым и переопределил переменные и методы наследуемого класса.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Примерно это будет выглядеть так:

```
# urls.py
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.main_page, name='main_page'),
]


# views.py
def main_page(request):
    articles = Article.objects.all().order_by('-date')
    rigs = Rig.objects.all().order_by('-date')

    response_data = {
        'articles': articles,
        'rigs': rigs,
    }

    return render(request, 'main_page/main_page.html', response_data)
```

Comment: сделал так же, не работает (сама страница работает, но объекты не выводит)

Comment: Потому что в шаблоне нужно сделать изменения в соответствии с названием переменных, которые вы передаёте в шаблонизатору.

Comment: Спасибо, всё работает, но выводит все объекты, а мне нужно определённое количество. Можно ли это как-то настроить?

Comment: Да, конечно. Вы можете использовать пагинацию, которую предоставляет Django (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/pagination/).
Или использовать высокоуровневые классы, которые Django предоставляет уже с пагинацией. Или ограничением в QuerySet'е.
Если мой ответ Вам помог. Пожалуйста, зачтите его как верный.