# Вывод определённого количества статей на страницу

Tags: python, django

Уже обращался по поводу этой темы, вопрос решили, ([Вывод нескольких классов на 1 url адрес](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1088628/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%85-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bd%d0%b0-1-url-%d0%b0%d0%b4%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81)). Но для меня осталось непонятным как вывести только определённое количество статей.

Мне нужно сделать так, что бы выводилось только 3 самых новых модели первого типа (rig) и 1 самая новая модель другого типа (article). Знаю, что нужно делать через paginator, но ума не приложу как. Надеюсь на вашу помощь)

Вот views.py файл:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rigs.models import Rig
from news.models import Article
from django.core.paginator import Paginator

def main_page(request):
    articles = Article.objects.all().order_by('-date')
    article = Paginator(articles, 1)
    rigs = Rig.objects.all().order_by('-date')
    rig = Paginator(articles, 3)

    response_data = {
        'articles': articles,
        'rigs': rigs,
    }

    return render(request, 'main_page/main_page.html', response_data)
```

Вот html файл с шаблоном:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    {% for post in rigs %}
          <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-img-top"><a href="{% url 'rig_detail' post.id %}"><img src="{{ post.image.url }}"></a></div>
                <div class="card-body">{{ post.title }}</div>
                <div class="card-footer">
                  <div class="card-footer-1 float-left">
                    <div class="layer-1"></div>
                    {% if post.price > 0 %}
                      <p class="mx-auto font-weight-bold font-italic">${{ post.price }}</p>
                    {% else %}
                      <p class="mx-auto font-weight-bold font-italic">Бесплатно</p>
                    {% endif %}
                  </div>
                  <div class="float-right">
                    {% if post.price > 0 %}
                      <a href="#" class="btn btn-success float-right align-middle ml-2 shadow-sm"><img src="media\rigs\shopping-cart.png" width="20px" height="20px"></a>
                      <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning float-left align-middle shadow-sm">Купить</a>
                    {% else %}
                      <a href="#" class="btn btn-info float-right align-middle shadow-sm">Скачать</a>
                    {% endif %}
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
          </div>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>

  <div class="container">
      {% for post in articles %}
        <div class="alert mx-auto article">
          <a href="{% url 'news_detail' post.id %}"><img src="{{ post.image.url }}"></a>
          <h4 class="display-4">{{ post.title }}</h4>
          <h4>{{ post.text }}</h4>
          <span>{{ post.date|date:"d E Y в H:i" }}</span>
        </div>
      {% endfor %}
  </div>
```

Так же, кто может, порекомендуйте книги или видеокурсы, которые стоит изучить для понимания и использования Django. Буду благодарен!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rigs = Rig.objects.all().order_by('-date')[:3]`

Со вторым думаю разберётесь

Comment: Спасибо огромное, не думал, что это так просто решается) Можете порекомендовать какую-либо литературу по Django в целом? Ещё раз спасибо

Comment: @IIIyTH1K tесли есть трудности с оф.док. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ то можно почитать эту книжку  django 2.1. практика создания веб-сайтов на python  Владимир Дронов. Правда там 2 версия джанги

Comment: @IIIyTH1K есть еще https://oz.by/books/more10893336.html тоже на русском, но есть ошибки в некоторых примерах книги

Comment: Не читайте Дронова. Прошу Вас.

Comment: @m0nte-cr1st0 а что не так? есть альтернативы на русском?

Comment: @user355827 зачем на русском?..

Comment: @m0nte-cr1st0 ну если спрашивают что почитать, значит явно проблемы с документацией, т.к. лучше нее нет ничего.